# How to scrape search results using WebGrude?

Tags: java, web-scraping

I recently used [WebGrude](https://github.com/beothorn/webGrude) for scrape some content from web pages. Then I tried to scrape some search results from e-bay. Here what tried,

```
@Page("http://www.ebay.com/sch/{0}")
public class PirateBay {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Search calls Browser, which loads the page on a PirateBay instance
        PirateBay search = PirateBay.search("iPhone");

        while (search != null) {
             search.magnets.forEach(System.out::println);
            search = search.nextPage();
        }
    }

    public static PirateBay search(String term) {
        return Browser.get(PirateBay.class, term);
    }

    private PirateBay() {
    }

    /*
* This selector matches all magnet links. The result is added to this String list.
* The default behaviour is to use the rendered html inside the matched tag, but here
* we want to use the href value instead.
*/
    @Selector(value = "#ResultSetItems a[href*=magnet]", attr = "href")
    public List<String> magnets;

/*
* This selector matches a link to the next page result, wich can be mapped to a PirateBay instance.
* The Link next gets the page on the href attribute of the link when method visit is called.
*/
    @Selector("a:has(img[alt=Next])")
    private Link<PirateBay> next;

    public PirateBay nextPage() {
        if (next == null)
            return null;
        return next.visit();
        }
    }
```

But the result is empty. How may I scrape search results using this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selector "#ResultSetItems a[href*=magnet]" selects the links where the href attribute has the string "magnet" on its value.

Here you can read more about Atribute selectors: [attribute_selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp)

What you want is "#ResultSetItems h3.lvtitle a"

To test your selectors there is this nice repl that uses Jsoup, the same library used by webgrude [Try jsoup](https://try.jsoup.org/)